# how to check for word in text file store in amazon s3 cloud storage against user input?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How do i match words in text file that is store in amazon s3 cloud storage, against user input in search bar, and then download the specific file?

Comment: tell me if the idea of doing `grep "keyword" s3://bucketname/*.*` did not come to your mind? :)

Comment: can you further explain this to me ? sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your files in Amazon S3 can be made public and then accessed using HttpURLConnection, as in:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    class Download
     {public static void main (String args[])
       {String u = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/Bucket/path/file.data";
        String d = download(u);
        System.err.println("Download "+u+"=\n"+d);
       }

      public static String download(String u)
       {final int B = 1024*1024; 

        try 
         {final URL url = new URL(u);
          final HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          c.connect();
          final int r = c.getResponseCode(); 
          if (r != 200) 
           {System.err.println("Got response code "+r+", expected 200, cannot download "+u);
            return null;
           }
          System.err.println("Content length="+c.getContentLength());

          final InputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), B);
          final byte data[] = new byte[B];
          String o = "";

          for(int n = i.read(data); n != -1; n = i.read(data))
           {o += new String(data, 0, n);
           }

          i.close();
          return o;
         }
        catch (Exception e) 
         {System.err.println("Cannot download "+u+" due to "+e);
         }
        return null;
       }
     }
```

If you are unable to make these files public you will have to go the more complex route of using Amazon IAM to create a user, assign the user privileges, generate a key/secret combination and then use the Amazon AWS SDK for Java documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html. Please post back here if you need help with that route.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [cloudbash.sh](http://cloudbash.sh) - not just grep, any linux tools for your data on S3.